# Required String parameter 'email' is not present

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot, postman

Не удаётся через postman сделать запрос, всё проверил, у меня в бд email представлен как varchar(255). Использую postgresql. Ошибка: Required String parameter 'email' is not present. Воспользовался [ответом](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37107570/exception-org-springframework-web-bind-missingservletrequestparameterexception), выставил вот так: `@RequestParam(value = "params", required = false) String params` у каждого принимаемого значение, но это не помогло, в итоге программа сообщила, что мы ничего не отправили. С чем это вообще может быть связано? Правильный ведь запрос, также как и принимаемые параметры корректны.

Как выглядит запрос:

```
{
    "email" : "qwerty@mail.ru",
    "name" : "Вася",
    "surname" : "Пушкин",
    "phone" : 1234562,
    "role":"ADMIN"
}
```

Entity USER

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "user", schema = "task")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST,
            CascadeType.REFRESH
    })
    @JoinColumn(name = "id")
    private List<Role> role;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
    private Set<Contract> contract;

    @Column(name = "surname", nullable = false)
    private String surname;
    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "email", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String email;
    @Column(name = "phone", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private Integer phone;
}
```

Контроллер, который принимает:

```
@PostMapping
    public String userPostAdd(@RequestParam String email, @RequestParam Integer phone, @RequestParam String name, @RequestParam String surname, @RequestParam String role) {
        Roles roles = null;
        System.out.println("ТЕСТ");
        System.out.println(roles.equalsName(role));
        System.out.println("ТЕСТ");
        //if ()
        //userRepository.save(requestUserDetails);
        return "Пользователь добавлен";
    }
```

Добавляю логи

```
"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.4\jbr\bin\java.exe" "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.4\lib\idea_rt.jar=55224:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.4\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath C:\Users\VGilenko\IdeaProjects\taskspring\target\classes;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-data-jpa\2.2.0.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-aop\2.2.0.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-aop-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter\2.2.0.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot\2.2.0.RELEASE\spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-autoconfigure\2.2.0.RELEASE\spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-logging\2.2.0.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-logging-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-classic\1.2.3\logback-classic-1.2.3.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-core\1.2.3\logback-core-1.2.3.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-to-slf4j\2.12.1\log4j-to-slf4j-2.12.1.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-api\2.12.1\log4j-api-2.12.1.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\jul-to-slf4j\1.7.28\jul-to-slf4j-1.7.28.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\org\yaml\snakeyaml\1.25\snakeyaml-1.25.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aop\5.2.0.RELEASE\spring-aop-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\org\aspectj\aspectjweaver\1.9.4\aspectjweaver-1.9.4.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-jdbc\2.2.0.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-jdbc-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\com\zaxxer\HikariCP\3.4.1\HikariCP-3.4.1.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jdbc\5.2.0.RELEASE\spring-jdbc-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\jakarta\activation\jakarta.activation-api\1.2.1\jakarta.activation-api-1.2.1.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\jakarta\persistence\jakarta.persistence-api\2.2.3\jakarta.persistence-api-2.2.3.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\jakarta\transaction\jakarta.transaction-api\1.3.3\jakarta.transaction-api-1.3.3.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\org\springframework\data\spring-data-jpa\2.2.0.RELEASE\spring-data-jpa-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\org\springframework\data\spring-data-commons\2.2.0.RELEASE\spring-data-commons-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-orm\5.2.0.RELEASE\spring-orm-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-context\5.2.0.RELEASE\spring-context-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-expression\5.2.0.RELEASE\spring-expression-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-tx\5.2.0.RELEASE\spring-tx-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-beans\5.2.0.RELEASE\spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-core\5.2.0.RELEASE\spring-core-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jcl\5.2.0.RELEASE\spring-jcl-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.7.28\slf4j-api-1.7.28.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aspects\5.2.0.RELEASE\spring-aspects-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-data-rest\2.2.0.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-data-rest-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-web\2.2.0.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-web-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-json\2.2.0.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-json-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-jdk8\2.10.0\jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.10.0.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-jsr310\2.10.0\jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.10.0.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\module\jackson-module-parameter-names\2.10.0\jackson-module-parameter-names-2.10.0.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-validation\2.2.0.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-validation-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\jakarta\validation\jakarta.validation-api\2.0.1\jakarta.validation-api-2.0.1.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\validator\hibernate-validator\6.0.17.Final\hibernate-validator-6.0.17.Final.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-web\5.2.0.RELEASE\spring-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-webmvc\5.2.0.RELEASE\spring-webmvc-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\org\springframework\data\spring-data-rest-webmvc\3.2.0.RELEASE\spring-data-rest-webmvc-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\org\springframework\data\spring-data-rest-core\3.2.0.RELEASE\spring-data-rest-core-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\org\springframework\hateoas\spring-hateoas\1.0.0.RELEASE\spring-hateoas-1.0.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\com\jayway\jsonpath\json-path\2.4.0\json-path-2.4.0.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\net\minidev\json-smart\2.3\json-smart-2.3.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\net\minidev\accessors-smart\1.2\accessors-smart-1.2.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\org\ow2\asm\asm\5.0.4\asm-5.0.4.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\org\springframework\plugin\spring-plugin-core\2.0.0.RELEASE\spring-plugin-core-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\org\atteo\evo-inflector\1.2.2\evo-inflector-1.2.2.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-databind\2.10.0\jackson-databind-2.10.0.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-core\2.10.0\jackson-core-2.10.0.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-annotations\2.10.0\jackson-annotations-2.10.0.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-tomcat\2.2.0.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-tomcat-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\jakarta\annotation\jakarta.annotation-api\1.3.5\jakarta.annotation-api-1.3.5.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-core\9.0.27\tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-el\9.0.27\tomcat-embed-el-9.0.27.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-websocket\9.0.27\tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.27.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\org\postgresql\postgresql\42.2.16\postgresql-42.2.16.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\org\checkerframework\checker-qual\3.5.0\checker-qual-3.5.0.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\hibernate-core\5.4.20.Final\hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\org\jboss\logging\jboss-logging\3.4.1.Final\jboss-logging-3.4.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\javax\persistence\javax.persistence-api\2.2\javax.persistence-api-2.2.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\org\javassist\javassist\3.24.0-GA\javassist-3.24.0-GA.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\net\bytebuddy\byte-buddy\1.10.1\byte-buddy-1.10.1.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\antlr\antlr\2.7.7\antlr-2.7.7.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\org\jboss\spec\javax\transaction\jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec\1.1.1.Final\jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec-1.1.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\org\jboss\jandex\2.1.3.Final\jandex-2.1.3.Final.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\classmate\1.5.0\classmate-1.5.0.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\javax\activation\javax.activation-api\1.2.0\javax.activation-api-1.2.0.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\org\dom4j\dom4j\2.1.3\dom4j-2.1.3.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\common\hibernate-commons-annotations\5.1.0.Final\hibernate-commons-annotations-5.1.0.Final.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\javax\xml\bind\jaxb-api\2.3.1\jaxb-api-2.3.1.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jaxb\jaxb-runtime\2.3.2\jaxb-runtime-2.3.2.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\jakarta\xml\bind\jakarta.xml.bind-api\2.3.2\jakarta.xml.bind-api-2.3.2.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jaxb\txw2\2.3.2\txw2-2.3.2.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\com\sun\istack\istack-commons-runtime\3.0.8\istack-commons-runtime-3.0.8.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\org\jvnet\staxex\stax-ex\1.8.1\stax-ex-1.8.1.jar;C:\Users\VGilenko\.m2\repository\com\sun\xml\fastinfoset\FastInfoset\1.2.16\FastInfoset-1.2.16.jar innotechnum.task.Application

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.2.0.RELEASE)

2020-09-25 19:26:12.934  INFO 7764 --- [           main] innotechnum.task.Application             : Starting Application on VGilenko with PID 7764 (C:\Users\VGilenko\IdeaProjects\taskspring\target\classes started by VGilenko in C:\Users\VGilenko\IdeaProjects\taskspring)
2020-09-25 19:26:12.939  INFO 7764 --- [           main] innotechnum.task.Application             : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-09-25 19:26:14.198  INFO 7764 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2020-09-25 19:26:14.265  INFO 7764 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 59ms. Found 4 repository interfaces.
2020-09-25 19:26:14.930  INFO 7764 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-09-25 19:26:15.691  INFO 7764 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2020-09-25 19:26:15.707  INFO 7764 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2020-09-25 19:26:15.707  INFO 7764 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.27]
2020-09-25 19:26:15.845  INFO 7764 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2020-09-25 19:26:15.845  INFO 7764 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2770 ms
2020-09-25 19:26:16.224  INFO 7764 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2020-09-25 19:26:16.296  INFO 7764 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.20.Final
2020-09-25 19:26:16.512  INFO 7764 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.0.Final}
2020-09-25 19:26:16.745  INFO 7764 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2020-09-25 19:26:16.882  INFO 7764 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2020-09-25 19:26:16.907  INFO 7764 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL10Dialect
Hibernate: alter table if exists task.city add constraint FKtjrg7h2j3ehgycr3usqjgnc2u foreign key (id) references task.house
2020-09-25 19:26:17.915  WARN 7764 --- [           main] o.h.t.s.i.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl     : GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL "alter table if exists task.city add constraint FKtjrg7h2j3ehgycr3usqjgnc2u foreign key (id) references task.house" via JDBC Statement

org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "alter table if exists task.city add constraint FKtjrg7h2j3ehgycr3usqjgnc2u foreign key (id) references task.house" via JDBC Statement
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlString(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:559) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlStrings(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:504) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applyForeignKeys(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:433) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.performMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:249) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.doMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:114) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:184) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:73) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:316) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:469) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1259) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:391) ~[spring-orm-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:378) ~[spring-orm-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1862) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1799) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:595) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1108) ~[spring-context-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:868) ~[spring-context-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at innotechnum.task.Application.main(Application.java:15) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ОШИБКА: INSERT или UPDATE в таблице "city" нарушает ограничение внешнего ключа "fktjrg7h2j3ehgycr3usqjgnc2u"
  Подробности: Ключ (id)=(1) отсутствует в таблице "house".
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2553) ~[postgresql-42.2.16.jar:42.2.16]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2285) ~[postgresql-42.2.16.jar:42.2.16]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:323) ~[postgresql-42.2.16.jar:42.2.16]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:473) ~[postgresql-42.2.16.jar:42.2.16]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:393) ~[postgresql-42.2.16.jar:42.2.16]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:322) ~[postgresql-42.2.16.jar:42.2.16]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeCachedSql(PgStatement.java:308) ~[postgresql-42.2.16.jar:42.2.16]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:284) ~[postgresql-42.2.16.jar:42.2.16]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:279) ~[postgresql-42.2.16.jar:42.2.16]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.execute(ProxyStatement.java:95) ~[HikariCP-3.4.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.execute(HikariProxyStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-3.4.1.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    ... 33 common frames omitted

2020-09-25 19:26:17.957  INFO 7764 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2020-09-25 19:26:17.963  INFO 7764 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2020-09-25 19:26:19.150  INFO 7764 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2020-09-25 19:26:19.635  INFO 7764 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2020-09-25 19:26:19.639  INFO 7764 --- [           main] innotechnum.task.Application             : Started Application in 7.149 seconds (JVM running for 7.817)
2020-09-25 19:26:35.874  INFO 7764 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2020-09-25 19:26:35.875  INFO 7764 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2020-09-25 19:26:35.904  INFO 7764 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 29 ms
2020-09-25 19:26:35.958  WARN 7764 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required String parameter 'email' is not present]
```

Comment: Вообще, я по этому адресу делаю запрос: http://localhost:8080/user момент ENUM сейчас тестирую, как раз хотел посмотреть как правильно принимать параметр роли, чтобы проверить, есть такая роль или нет. А должна быть такая надпись "тест"? Ошибка, которая абсолютно всегда выскакивает: INSERT или UPDATE в таблице “user” нарушает ограничение внешнего ключа “fkjf7w******” Подробности: Ключ (id)=(1) отсутствует в таблице “landlord”

Comment: вы сами выложили код контроллера и пишите, что он принимает запрос, а в этом коде первые 2 строки: Roles roles = null; System.out.println("ТЕСТ"); Мне кажется, что должен, если туда действительно запрос прилетает...

Comment: Я понял про что вы. Нет, всё верно в этом плане. В сам контроллер не проходит, он проверку пройти не может, говорит, что Required String parameter 'email' is not present Что-то с параметрами не нравится. Будто бы найти не может

Comment: вариантов не так много. поставьте в метод в параметры required = false и посмотрите, что фактически вам приходит. а вы урл указали нормально, а то @PostMapping без параметров. а вообще нужен какой-то инструмент для того, чтобы подобные ошибки не допускать. я поднимаю свагер. там все автоматизировано, посему накосячить с запросом в принципе невозможно, зато всегда видно куда и с какими параметрами нужно обратиться

Comment: @Дмитрий делал уже так, он с каждым выдаёт такую ошибку. Если у всех поставить, то пишет про null

Comment: ок, тогда попробуйте так. все переменные из метода перенесите в класс. а свой контроллер измените так: public String userPostAdd(@ModelAttribute OurClass ourClass)

Comment: Я сейчас пытаюсь сделать вот так, он мне новую ошибку, но уже с ролями выводит, не знаю, правильно или нет делаю: `@RequestBody User user` Мне запрос приходит, но думаю, что с ролями не то что-то делаю теперь, потому что хочу произвести проверку, существует такая роль или нет (мой ЕНУМ вот такой: `TENANT ("tenant"), LANDLORD ("landlord"), ADMIN ("admin");` А проверку вот такую делаю:  `Roles roles = null;
        roles.equalsName(String.valueOf(user.getRole()));`

Comment: аннотацию измените с RequestBody на ModelAttribute. и это не проверка Roles roles = null; это присвоение переменной roles  значения null

Comment: Изменил, теперь пишет: No message available . А как мне тогда ещё обратиться к роли? Ибо нужно ведь инициализировать чем-то

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Контроллер был некорректным

```
@PostMapping
public String userPostAdd(@RequestParam String email, @RequestParam Integer phone, @RequestParam String name, @RequestParam String surname, @RequestParam String role) {
     //body
}
```

Так должно быть :

```
@PostMapping
public String userPostAdd(@RequestBody User user) {
     //body
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Я этот вопрос через JSONObject решил:

```
@PostMapping("/auth/login")
    public Map<String,Object> auth(@Valid @RequestBody JSONObject jsonObject) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException{        
        String eMail = jsonObject.get("e_mail").toString();
        String password = jsonObject.get("password").toString();
```

и Dependency

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.alibaba</groupId>
            <artifactId>fastjson</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.15</version>
        </dependency>
```